# Would it be possible to create a batch file or windows task for malware check?

Tags: windows, batch, malware

Would it be possible to create a batch file or windows task that would monitor all drives for any new files showing up, calculate their hash and check virus total for malware flag, then if malware flag exists, remove all permissions with icacls from that file?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to replace a proper malware scanner with a batch file? What research have you done so far to resolve the question? Please don't answer with a comment, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1769409/edit) your question instead.

Comment: The two steps here are triggering events on file writes and changes, and calculating hashes and checking them against your prefered online source. Triggering events on file writes and reads is probably going to trigger FAR more times than you expect, and will consume far more resources than you'd like. Also, malware hides itself and so your task scheduler based method is unlikely to work. The task scheduler is well documented. Second is probably pretty simple if it is supported. So, what research have you done and what have you tried, and also what Peregrino said.